# How to find amicable numbers between 200 and 400?

Tags: python

I am using only for and if loop to find amicable numbers between 200 and 400, which is only 220 and 287. I try using this code, but for some reason, it is not printing these two numbers. Where in the code is wrong? I don't want use functions.

```
for num in range(200 , 401):
    sum1 = 0
    for i in range(1 , num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            sum1 += i
    for num2 in range(200 , 401):
        sum2 = 0
        for j in range(1 , num2 + 1):
            if num2 % j == 0:
                sum2 += j
    if sum1 == num2 and sum2 == num:
        print("{} and {} are amicable numbers.".format(num , num2))
```

I expect the output to be "220 and 287 are amicable numbers.", but the terminal is leaving it blank without any error messages.

Comment: both sum1 and sum2 equals 961 in your program after the loops

Comment: Why do you think 220 & 287 are amicable numbers?

Comment: I'd highly recommend stepping through your code in a debugger before posting here. Issues like this almost always can be found that way. If you're not using a debugger yet, you absolutely should.

Comment: Remove the `+1`. You only have to sum *proper* divisors.

Comment: I found the problem, thanks to Bakuriu, I replaced +1 with floor division + 1

Answer (score 0):

The [amicable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amicable_numbers) you are looking for are 220 and 284. A number is not a [proper divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor#Further_notions_and_facts) of itself, so you should adjust your ranges to exclude the number as a divisor of itself. Also, your if statement is only comparing the sums when `num2 == 400` because your indentation is off. I find all the nested loops a bit hard to read, so here is an approach that seems a bit cleaner to me.

```
for a in range(200, 401):
    b = sum(j for j in range(1, a) if a % j == 0)
    x = sum(j for j in range(1, b) if b % j == 0)
    if a == x:
        print(f'{a} and {b} are amicable numbers');

# 220 and 284 are amicable numbers
# 284 and 220 are amicable numbers
```